# How to get video url in product list page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, product-video, product-listing

I want to get product video url in product list page.I am try below code but its not works for my end

```
<?php if($_product->getVideo()): ?>`

            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideo() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code :

```
 <iframe width="640" height="480" src="<?php echo $image->getVideoUrl(); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: its not working